# Why is Ubuntu 14.04 using too much RAM..?

Tags: compiz, ram

Compiz in earlier versions of Ubuntu took around 60-65 MB of RAM.
In Ubuntu 14.04, it is taking around 205-201 MB.
And Nautilus took 35 MB of RAM in earlier versions, it is taking a minimum of 65 MB.
My total RAM usage since 13.10 was around 500-600 MB.
It has been increased to 1.2 GB of usage since the installation of 14.04

Comment: Were you using 32-bit version before and have now installed the 64-bit version?

Comment: No, I always used a 64-bit version.

Comment: What about cpu usage, is it lower than before? I am asking this because I want to know if they finally decided to use more RAM to speed up the system, and take the pressure away from the CPU which was abusively used in the previous versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: CPU usage is same. It shows the same activity, as it showed in 13.10 (system monitor)

Comment: With the availability of RAM there is little incentive for developers to be as RAM cautious as they once were and foo 2.0 is always going to be larger, more complex, and use more ram then foo 1.0 . A better question(s) are what problem are you having? how much ram do you have? why so you think even using 1 Gb RAM is a problem ? I have 4 GB ram available, should it just sit unused ?

Comment: I have 2 Gigs of RAM and programs are loading a little slower than previous version.

Comment: With 2 GiB of RAM you should probably be using Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Btw. you should rather use a 32bit with 2GiB

Comment: Right now I am using some distro based on Ubuntu core, and they had this great idea to fool the system to believe that computer hardware is actually a few steps behind its real capabilities. This proved to be an excellent workaround for both ram and cpu usage.

Comment: @the_Seppi why ? I use kde just fine with 1 GB ram ?

Comment: your "slowdowns" are unrelated to ram use. "slow" is subjective and most often related to your graphics card, although I have seen it with wireless. Try k/x ubuntu.

Comment: But according to your question I assume you're using Unity. And unity uses way more resources than even KDE.

Comment: **Aditya**: I DID switch from 32-bit to 64-bit with the installation of 14.04, and now my memory keeps going far higher than it did, and I keep getting momentarily bogged down with nearly unusable performance as if a process is running wild (mouse cursor travels poorly, menus take minutes to open, etc). **Is there a known issue with firefox or am I missing something about 14.04 or 64-bit things that I'm not aware of in regards to memory or performance? Because 13.10 (32bit) worked totally fine...** I suspect possibly firefox or something related to software-center type activity going wrong, I'

Comment: @the_Seppi I would like to use a 32-bit version, but on Macs you cannot install and run the 32-bit Ubuntu version.

Comment: I get the same problem with 14.04. 4GB of ram, Ubuntu 12.04 worked like a breeze, and now with 14.04 the system often freezes up for long periods of time and memory even after just starting up is almost completely used.

Comment: I found a way around for the system freeze. press ctrl+alt+f2, then again go back to the graphical tty(genereally it is ctrl+alt+f7).

Comment: In my case it was `unity-scope-clementine` that caused the memory leak. [Uninstall it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2213694) and unity is sane now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I just had the same problem and have now resolved it for myself. I believe that this issue is swap related.

I have also recently reinstalled 14.04 on whole disk and was previously using 13.10 successfully and well. I too noticed my that my ram was mostly staying around 1.2GB of use, just as stated in the person's question. I strongly suspect that the person probably used whole disk encryption which is a part of the Ubuntu install which likely caused this issue.

My symptoms were that occasionally Ubuntu would become almost complete unresponsive even with a typical light amount of open programs and activity, which had been performing acceptably on my old Ubuntu install. At first I thought it was Firefox or Software Center related.

Dell Optiplex 780 (small form factor/sff)

Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GHz × 2

Memory 2GB (plan on upgrading to 8 or more very soon)

Video Intel® Q45/Q43

I noticed in the System Monitor program, that in the resources tab it showed swap as "not available" (or something along those lines). This was a fresh install of 14.04. I used whole disk encryption, and decided it was probably related to that. I checked for the existence of my swap partition in the Disks program, and saw that the swap partition did exist at least and seemed appropriate. It was called: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1` which is correct.

I also confirmed it's existence in terminal with:

```
sudo fdisk -a
```

I did some googling and decided it may not have been activated as swap, even though the space was created, so I deactivated swap:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Then I told it to recognize that space as swap:

```
sudo mkswap /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1
```

Then I turned swap on:

```
sudo swapon -a
```

I then received a message about cryptsetup swap blah blah blah, which is appropriate, but I did NOT receive a message regarding `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1`, despite having received one before I did these steps.

I reopened System Monitor and saw that it does indeed now recognize and use my swap space. Just for good measure, I restarted my computer, and it has been running quickly and normally again, just like before installing 14.04.

I think I may not have even noticed many problems had I not had such low RAM, which makes having swap space activated quite important.